# Format JSON in PowerBI

Tags: json, influxdb, powerbi-desktop

i want to show data from influxDB on PowerBI through HTTP API end point. 
following is the JSON i get from Influx while hitting the url

```
     {
        "results": [
            {
                "statement_id": 0,
                "series": [
                    {
                        "name": "cpu",
                        "columns": [
                            "time",
                            "value"
                        ],
                        "values": [
                            [
                                "2018-09-13T11:03:57.1175792Z",
                                0.64
                            ],
                            [
                                "2018-09-13T11:09:58.2259457Z",
                                100
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

when i try to create table from it in PowerBI. it shows all columns in a row.[here is the image that i got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8B4a.jpg)

PS: i cant change the JSON

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from Power bi community. here is the [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Format-JSON-into-table-PowerBI/m-p/515937#M241137).

and this one is query.

```
let
Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\generated.json")),
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
#"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value"),
#"Expanded Value2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"statement_id", "series"}, {"Value.statement_id", "Value.series"}),
#"Expanded Value.series" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value2", "Value.series"),
#"Expanded Value.series1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value.series", "Value.series", {"name", "columns", "values"}, {"Value.series.name", "Value.series.columns", "Value.series.values"}),
#"Expanded Value.series.columns" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value.series1", "Value.series.columns"),
#"Expanded Value.series.values" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value.series.columns", "Value.series.values"),
#"Expanded Value.series.values1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value.series.values", "Value.series.values"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Value.series.values1",{"Value.series.name", "Value.statement_id", "Name"}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value.series.columns", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.series.columns.1", "Value.series.columns.2"}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Value.series.columns.2"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Value.custom", each if [Value.series.columns.1]="time" and Value.Is([Value.series.values],Int64.Type) then null else if [Value.series.columns.1]="value" and not Value.Is([Value.series.values],Int64.Type) then null else [Value.series.values]),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Value.custom] <> null),
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Value.series.values"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns2", {"Value.series.columns.1"}, {{"all data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index",1,1),type table}}),
#"Expanded all data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "all data", {"Value.custom", "Index"}, {"all data.Value.custom", "all data.Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded all data", List.Distinct(#"Expanded all data"[Value.series.columns.1]), "Value.series.columns.1", "all data.Value.custom"),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"all data.Index", "Index"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```